# Excel 2013 Backstage customization problems

Tags: xml, vba, excel

I work in a public library system and Office 2013 has created issues with our patrons saving files and I am trying to simplify the process.  I intend to hide all of "save" options in backstage and create a custom tab called "Save Here" to remove this confusion.

I have pieced together some XML for the customUI that works for changing the backstage view, however, I cannot get the callback to VBA code inside the xlsm file to work properly. I also need a way to make this work when Excel starts.

I tried putting the Excel macro enabled document in the XLSTART folder and while this makes it work on startup - users would be directly editing my workbook.  If I hide the view to make them create a new page, then the customUI will not work.  Even with the file in XLSTART when you close the document it also gives "Microsoft Excel has stopped working.." so I need help.

Finally, I have tried putting the VBA code inside "This Workbook" in the vba editor, as well as creating a new module and putting it there.  If I put it in "This Workbook" I get an error about it not finding the "SaveAction" macro.  If I put it in the module, it comes closer to working, with the above problems.

**RIBBON XML**

```
    <customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui">
    <backstage>
           <button idMso="FileSave" visible="false"/>
           <button idMso="FileSaveAs" visible="false"/>
           <button idMso="FileOpen" visible="true"/>
           <button idMso="FileClose" visible="true"/>
           <button idMso="ApplicationOptionsDialog" visible="false"/>
           <button idMso="FileExit" visible="false"/>
           <tab idMso="TabInfo" visible="false"/>
           <tab idMso="TabRecent" visible="false"/>
           <tab idMso="TabNew" visible="false"/>
           <tab idMso="TabPrint" visible="true"/>
           <tab idMso="TabShare" visible="false"/>
           <tab idMso="TabHelp" visible="false"/>
           <tab idMso="TabSave" visible="false"/>
           <tab idMso="TabPublish" visible="false"/>
           <tab idMso="TabOfficeStart" visible="true"/>
       <tab id="MyTab" insertAfterMso="TabPrint" label="Save Here" ColumnWidthPercent="30">
          <firstColumn>                     
            <group id="FirstGroup" label="Save Here" helperText="Click here to Save">           
                <primaryItem>                       
                    <button id="BigButton" label="Patron Save Location" isDefinitive="true" onAction="SaveAction"/>                 
                </primaryItem>                      
            </group>                        
          </firstColumn>
       </tab>
    </backstage>
    </customUI>
```

**EXCEL-VBA**

```
    Sub SaveAction(control As IRibbonControl)
       'Saves any changes to the workbook.
       ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs
    End Sub
```

RE: Comments after David's solution below:

Explanation of what I am trying to accomplish.  When our patrons use Office 2013 and they go to the file menu, this launches Office Backstage - with a long list of options.  A lot of our patrons get confused at this point as they are not familiar with any version of Office.  You can disable backstage in the applications options, but this does not disable the options under File>SaveAs.  Options such as Skydrive - which can be removed, I know, but computer and add a place are still present.  I am trying to make it as simple as possible by giving them one choice so staff do not have to spend a lot of time answering questions about where to save a document.  This being explained, your final comment below accomplished my task and thereby answers my question, so am marking the answer, but wouldn't mind hearing about other or better ways to dumb down backstage.

Comment: Hey thanks for adding some comments about what you're trying to solve! I think the current approach should work for that. When I first read your Q, I assumed you were trying to limit or control the user's ability to save the file to specific locations, But if you're simply trying to "dumb down" the backstage view, then this is a good way to do it.  Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an error in your XML, it should be: `columnWidthPercent` not `ColumnWidthPercent`.

> I also need a way to make this work when Excel starts.

Put the ribbon code in an XLAM Add-in file and configure the computers so that this Add-in is loaded to Excel Application.

Put the VBA callback in a standard code module.

Example:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1v0s8ldwHRYMUNWZFlFdVExYjg/view?usp=sharing

RE: Comments

You'll want to modify your procedure like:

```
Sub SaveAction(control As IRibbonControl)
   Dim fdlg
   Set fdlg = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)
   fdlg.Show
   fdlg.Execute
End Sub
```

You may need to modify this further for error-handling.

**NOTE**

This solution assumes that users will not be able to change the Add-ins that are installed on the computer, nor unload existing Add-ins, etc.

Comment: add ins can perform actions on newly created documents and well as people opening their own documents, as long as the add in is present on the library computers?  Also, the VBA code I listed above defaults to save and not saveas when I run it, is there something wrong there?

Comment: Yes, as long as the add in is present and installed, it should work on *any* Excel document opened on the computer.  Regarding the save/saveAs, I don't know if there is an issue or not: I assumed you were trying to prevent them from saving to some other location, and made that comment just in case you are trying to somehow prevent them from doing certain save/saveAs.

Comment: Ok.  I put the xlam file you provided in the XLStart and it seems to work except if you actually click the button that is created in backstage it saves the current workbook as book1.xls and does not give them an option to name the file, as SaveAs should. Is there any way to prompt the user to name the file and not just save as book1.xls?

Comment: The xlam probably shouldn't go in XLSTART folder. It should go in the AddIns folder, and you will have to enable the Add-in via Excel's Developer tab or through registry entry.

Comment: I really appreciate your help.  I moved it to the add in folder and enabled it in the developer toolbar.  It still does the same thing as I mentioned in last comment.  It saves a document named book1.xls and does not give an option to save as.  If book1.xls is there, it will give an error that it exists and ask to replace it.

Comment: Try using the FileDialog method (revision above in my answer), although at this point I don't understand what behavior you're trying to prevent by overriding the Backstage view.  Perhaps if you better describe what problems you're trying to solve, there may be other solutions.